# PHP - Handling HTML checkbox array

Tags: php, html, checkbox

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE**

I follow the exact steps that the my question is a suppose "duplicate" of and I get a completely different result.

I have a form that has 5 checkboxes. When I submit the form and I print the value of the checkbox array I get the word `on` for each checkbox that was selected instead of the value.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label style="width:auto !important;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="additional[]" value="contact">
    Contact Form
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label style="width:auto !important;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="additional[]" value="google">
    Google Map
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label style="width:auto !important;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="additional[]" value="sub">
    Subscribe Feature
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label style="width:auto !important;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="additional[]" value="caro">
    Image carousel
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label style="width:auto !important;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="additional[]" value="bar">
    Search Bar
  </label>
</div>
```

This is my PHP to get the value of `additional[]` when the form is submitted,

```
$add = $_POST["additional"];
```

I then loop through them to see each checkbox that was selected,

```
$addThings = "";

foreach($add as $value) {
$addThings.= " $value ";
}
echo $addThings;
```

The output is this,

```
on on on
```

It displays an `on` for each checkbox that has been selected.

How can I get it to display the actual value?

Comment: are you sure you're on the right form? your checkbox values has `value="bar"`, the default value is `on` when this is omitted. no one would be able to reproduce this based on the question above

Comment: The issue is not reproduced

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The suppose duplicate answer does not help me in this situation. Did you even read my question?

Comment: Your form is a duplicate. My guess is that, you're not showing us full code and that is why @TamilSelvan said they were unable to reproduce. I on the other hand, was able to successfully test this using proper form syntax, using a POST method. If your form does not contain that, and you're relying on another method to achieve this, such as JS/Ajax; then add it to your question. As it stands, it's still a duplicate. If you are using form tags and a POST method isn't included; forms default to GET.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php